# Is it valid to place Draw 4 on a Draw 4, while having the colour set by the first Draw 4?

Tags: uno

I was playing Uno and one player placed down a Draw 4 card, and set it to a colour (let's say red). The next player played a Draw 4 card, even though they had the colour specified by the first player (let's say red).

Is that a valid play? So, if I were to challenge the second player, would I win the challenge?

Comment: What position were you in relative to the person you believe illegally played Wild Draw 4? Were you next, or was someone else?

Comment: Unclear what you're asking. If player 1 plays a Wild Draw 4, player 2 must pick up 4 cards, player 3 is the next to play a card; unless you're playing house rules that instead of picking up 4 cards player 2 could "defend" with a Wild Draw 4, making player 3 pick up 8 cards. Whenever I've played that house rule, player 2's other cards are irrelevant as they have no chance to play them, but being a house rule it could have any sort of caveats of the house's choice. Without clarification of whether player 2 should have been picking up or playing red this question is unclear.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## You would win the challenge

The rule is, you may not play a Wild Draw 4 unless you do not have any card that matches the color of the top card on the stack.

Answer (score 4):

No, it's not valid to do so since according to the Mattel's UNO rules the next player forfeit their turn and MUST draw 4 cards from the pile.
*But for the player after the next player (who had to pick up the 4 cards) it's a valid play.*

Anything else is just house rules...

From mattel.com: https://service.mattel.com/instruction_sheets/42001pr.pdf

> Wild Draw 4 Card - This card allows you to call the next color played and requires the next player to pick 4 cards from the DRAW pile and FORFEIT his/her turn.

Note: The player in turn (after the player who had to draw 4 cards) may play a Wild Draw 4 Card with consideration to the color chosen by the player playing the first Wild Draw 4 Card.
So in that case you could say that a Wild Draw 4 Card could be played on a Wild Draw 4 Card.

Remember that it's only the next player who can make the challenge.

> Wild Draw 4 Card - ... Only the person required to draw the 4 cards can make the challenge.

Answer (score -3):

You can put a 4+ On top of a 4+ next player for this example has to pick up 8 cards

Comment: Welcome to Board & Card Games! Can you support this answer with a passage from the relevant **official** rules?

Comment: The official rules do not allow for doubling of card effects and that would be a house rule.

Answer (score -4):

Yes it is a valid play because when the next player puts another +4 it becomes +8 and goes to the 3rd person but what is not valid is that if someone has a +4 or wild card you cant choose the same color.

Comment: That is not the case in the official rules. Any draw card causes the next player to draw the cards and lose their turn and only in house rules do they get to stack draw cards.

Comment: Assuming no house rules are in effect, this answer is wrong on multiple counts. Wild Draw 4's only stack if a WD4 stacking house rule is being used (and they can still be challenged as normal), otherwise the only actions the immediately following player can take are drawing the 4 cards OR challenging the WD4 play. Furthermore, there is no requirement that the color declared when playing a Wild (or Wild Draw 4) card be different from the current color on top of the discard pile.

Comment: Based on [this meta post](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1721/should-very-low-quality-answers-be-deleted) I don't see any reason this should be deleted (unless the author decides to based on the feedback).

Answer (score -4):

No, you may not place two draw four cards on top of each other.

Comment: This is not correct, the next player to play may also play a draw 4 if they do not have the color that was called.

Answer (score -5):

I have seen several versions of the official rules. Some of them (mainly early versions) specifically allowed playing a draw 4 on a draw 4.

Comment: As a Wild Card, it can be played on anything, yeah. The question is about the restriction against playing it *when you have a card of the appropriate color in hand*. None of the official rules provide relief from those restrictions based on the previous card play being a Wild Draw 4, as far as I know. If there is such an official version of the rules, please cite it.